# Get index of the specific td in tr by XPath

Tags: reactjs, selenium, xpath, cucumberjs

I have thead and tbody in the table. 
Thead contains a few s in . Each of it have an id. I need to find the index of td in thead by id and then find  by index in tbody.

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <td data-date="2019-08-05"></td>
     <td data-date="2019-08-06"></td> //find index of this element
     <td data-date="2019-08-07"></td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td> //find this element by found index
    <td>ccc</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 upd
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <td data-date="2019-08-05"></td>
     <td data-date="2019-08-06"></td> 
     <td data-date="2019-08-07"></td> 
     <td data-date="2019-08-08"></td> //find index of this element
     <td data-date="2019-08-09"></td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="rrrr">event1 2019-08-06</td>
    <td class="rrrr">event1 2019-08-07</td>
    <td class="rrrr"event1 2019-08-08</td> //find this element by found index
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="rrrr">event2 2019-08-07</td>
    <td class="rrrr">event2 2019-08-08</td> //find this element by found index
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the index of `<td id="2"></td> ` inside `tr` in `thead` always equal to its `id` value (both are '2', in this case) or is it a coincidence?

Comment: @JackFleeting no it's abstract value. id can have any value

Comment: Got it; I would recommend you edit your question to change the `id` values to some other random characters, just to clarify.

Comment: @JackFleeting ok, i changed it.

Comment: I edited your code a bit for more clarity; see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This xpath expression

```
//tbody//td[count(//thead//td[@data-date='2019-08-06']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

selects

```
<td>bbb</td>
```

Comment: @DebanjanB - Thank you; much appreciated, especially coming from you!

Comment: @JackFleeting, Hi again, after some upd of code, i have td. this tag can have rowspan and can not have it, but always have class "rrr". I need to find tds with same attributes(with rowspan or not) and then find by index find td in the next tr by this index. please, help

Comment: @JohnBrewer - I'm not sure are entirely understand your comment, but as a general SO policy, you should post a new question with the new, updated code, so more people can see it.

Comment: @JackFleeting Ok, done, link to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757779/get-second-event-from-fullcalendar-by-xpath