# Get second event from FullCalendar by xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, cucumberjs

I have `FullCalendar` in my project:
https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/fullcalendar

I have 2 events at one day, I found first event by this code:

```
//tbody//td[count(//thead//td[@data-date='2019-08-06']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

And I need to find second or more events.

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td data-date="2019-08-05"></td>
   <td data-date="2019-08-06"></td> 
   <td data-date="2019-08-07"></td> 
   <td data-date="2019-08-08"></td> //find index of this element
   <td data-date="2019-08-09"></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2"></td>
   <td rowspan="2" class="rrrr">event1 2019-08-06</td>
   <td class="rrrr">event1 2019-08-07</td>
   <td class="rrrr">event1 2019-08-08</td> //find this element by found index
   <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rrrr">event2 2019-08-07</td>
    <td class="rrrr">event2 2019-08-08</td> //find this element by found index
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

UPD
   [How work //div[@class='fc-content-skeleton'][.//td[@data-date='2019-09-03']]//tbody/tr/td[count(//thead//td[@data-date='2019-09-03']/preceding-sibling::*)+1] at second day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvmZo.gif)

Comment: Searching by index may not work this time because your target date is #4 in `thead/tr`, but "event 2" is #2 in `tbody/tr[2]`.

Comment: @JackFleeting Yep, but day with one event have class="" and rowspan, and day with same amount of events with my day have only class="", so probably need to count preceding-sibling days without rowspan

Comment: So just to be clear: is it always the case that in each `tbody/tr` there are only two `td`s with `class="rrrr"` (and which have no `rowspan`) and that your target event is always the 2nd of these two (like it is in `tbody/tr[2]`)?

Comment: @JackFleeting No, if one day have 2 events and another day have 1 event, day with 1 event have class and rowspan, if day have not events - only rowspan, if some days have 2 events - only class, and target event place depends from how many preceding-sibling days have same or more amount of events

Comment: Then if i understand you correctly, the index location of `date-date` on `thead/tr` is really irrelevant. Are you simply just trying to select all events taking place on a specific `date-date`?

Comment: @JackFleeting, no, for first <tr> from tbody no, but for next tr yes

Comment: But you xml in the questions says about the first `tr` in `tbody`: "<td class="rrrr">event1 2019-08-08</td> //find this element by found index"?

Comment: @JackFleeting, this work by your answer from previous question, and now I need to find second event

Answer (score 1):

I would use the below xpath to get all the events and then iterate them. So, you don't have to worry even if the events' count change between the dates.

```
//div[@class='fc-content-skeleton'][.//td[@data-date='2017-02-12']]//tbody/tr/td[count(//thead//td[@data-date='2017-02-12']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

If you want to access any specific event then you can do it using the index as shown below. (wrapped entire xpath in `()` and then provide the index in `[]`).

```
(//div[@class='fc-content-skeleton'][.//td[@data-date='2017-02-12']]//tbody/tr/td[count(//thead//td[@data-date='2017-02-12']/preceding-sibling::*)+1])[2]
```

[image]